# How to write a general pattern in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have multiple programs which share the same structure of compilation.

```
test_variance : test_variance.o
    $(CPP) -o test_variance.exe $(CFLAGS) test_variance.o $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)

test_variance_incremental: test_variance_incremental.o 
    $(CPP) -o test_variance_incremental.exe $(CFLAGS) test_variance_incremental.o $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)

test_hyper: test_hyper.o 
    $(CPP) -o test_hyper.exe $(CFLAGS) test_hyper.o $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)

test_hyper.o: test_hyper.cpp
    $(CPP)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c test_hyper.cpp

test_variance_incremental.o: test_variance_incremental.cpp
    $(CPP)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c test_variance_incremental.cpp

test_variance.o : test_variance.cpp 
    $(CPP)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c test_variance.cpp
```

So for compling .o, I can use the pattern

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<
```

I wonder if there is a general pattern for compling the executive. I've tried

```
TARGETS = test_variance test_variance_incremental test_hyper

$(TARGETS): $@.o
    $(CPP) -o $@.exe $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)
```

But Make tells me there is no input files and I think my usage of $@ is wrong. Any advice?

Comment: I don't know what's in `CFLAGS`, but generally we use those only when compiling. When linking, the options should be in `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: It's often the case that you want to use `CFLAGS` on the link line as well.  Some flags should be specified on both, and there's nothing in `CFLAGS` that would be a problem during link.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. This piece of code is actually borrowed from my tutor, so I learn the conventions from him. Anyway, I will note it.

Comment: @NH000 CFLAGS  = -O3 -std=c++11 '-DCOMPLEX=std::complex<double>'  in my make file, regarding what MadScientist said, I think it's better to use CPPFLAGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CC` and `CFLAGS` for compiling C code, and `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for compiling C++ code.  `CPP` (in make) is used for running the C preprocessor (only).  The standard variable to hold libraries is `LDLIBS`.

If you use these variables then you don't even need to define your own rules at all: there are built-in rules in make that already know how to compile and link C++ programs.  All you need is this:

```
TARGETS = test_variance test_variance_incremental test_hyper

all: $(TARGETS)
```

Anyway, if you want to write it explicitly you can write:

```
TARGETS = test_variance test_variance_incremental test_hyper

all: $(TARGETS)

% : %.o
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

(you should definitely not name the target `test_variance`, but then have your link line build `test_variance.exe`: the target name and the file that the recipe builds must always be the same).

Comment: OP may also be interested in [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage)

Comment: It seems that make cannot match %:%.o, I change it to $(TARGETS):%:%.o and it works well.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean "have your link line build test_variance.exe"? Could you give a concrete example? Edit: I've tried rewrite `TARGETS = test_variance.exe test_variance_incremental.exe test_hyper.exe VerifyW.exe` and `$(TARGETS): %.exe: %.o` that works out.

Comment: Make can absolutely match `% : %.o`.  In fact as I said, there's a built-in rule that does it so it definitely works.  If it didn't work for you there must have been something else about your makefile that you didn't show us.

Comment: Yes, setting `TARGETS` that way will work.  But what you had originally was a target of `test_variance` and a recipe that built the file `test_variance.exe`.  That's not right.  Your recipe needs to build the exact same file as the target.  So you have to either use a target of `test_variance.exe` if that's what you want to build, or else have your recipe build `test_variance` (without the `.exe` extension).  Basically, if your recipe is ever building a file that is not exactly `$@` (for example, `$@.exe` is not exactly `$@`) then your recipe is not correct.